# use pre-trained word2vec to create the wordvector

Tags: python, word2vec, word-embeddings

I'm quite new to machine learning and Nlp.
I want to do my project using word2vec.

let say I hava word vector

> [ [drawing,painting], [reading,game,assembly]]

this represent the person1 and person2's hobby list. 
I want to transform this word vector to matrix using word2vector

let say drawing and painting has high similarity

> [[0000001,0000010],[001000,1000011,001000]]

if im using word2vec to make this vector. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which python library you are using. usually it is stored as dictionary in word2vec model. For example if you want to get word vectors for the word "A" you should do something like this.

```python
vector = model["A"]
```

Or sometimes there are functions like get_vector(key) where key is a word which you want to get the vector for it.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440803/how-to-fetch-vectors-for-a-word-list-with-word2vec) answer out.

Now you can loop throw your word list and transform

```python
hobby_lists = [ [drawing,painting], [reading,game,assembly]]
[[model.get_vector(key) for key in hobby_list] for hobby_list in hobby_lists]
```